# Python Global Variable Not Working

Tags: python, global

I have an extremely long program for a Canasta game that I am writing, in it there is a variable that ends the turn of the player if it equals a certain value. However, the turn repeats itself.

I have read many different articles and posts on forums like this one, but none of these seem to work. I even have a debug system to print the value of the variable before the if statement, and the variable is the right value, but the if statement doesn't see the same value.

I can't give the entire code, as it is extremely long, but I can give the sections that use this variable. I am using Python 2.7.2 and cannot make files separate from the main file to import.

The first line of the program is:

```
endTurn=1
```

The following function is called when conditions to win the game are met, but I have not been able to test that this works because of the bug.

```
def winGame(player):
    global endTurn
    gameWinner=player
    gameWinner["score"]+=100
    endTurn=0
```

The following function is called when a move is made. The variable `decide` is a `raw_input()` variable.

```
def move(player,decide):
    global endTurn
    theMove=decide.lower()
    #if player says to end turn
    if theMove=="end":
        #until player discards something
        discarded=0
        while not discarded:
            displayHand(player)
            #ask player for discard
            discard=int(raw_input(" Enter the list number of the card you wish to discard:"))-1
            #if discard ID is in player's hand length
            if not discard<0 and not discard>len(player["hand"])-1:
                #add card to discard pile and remove from hand
                discardPile.append(player["hand"][discard])
                del(player["hand"][discard])
                discarded=1
        debug("Before changing, endTurn is %s"%str(endTurn))
        endTurn = 0
        debug("After changing, endTurn is %s"%str(endTurn))
    if theMove=="new book":
        newBook(player)
    if theMove=="add to book":
        addBook(player)
```

Here is where the turn should be ended. `turn(thePlayer)` repeats the function. The debug statement shows the correct value, 0, but the `if` still reads a 1. The function this is in also has the `global endTurn` at the top.

```
debug("If ending turn, endTurn of %s should be 0."%str(endTurn))
if endTurn==1:
    turn(thePlayer)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The code is available at http://labs.codecademy.com/CV9z#:workspace. I ask that anyone viewing the code does not modify it, so that other people can see the true code.

Comment: As a beginner please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) closely!

Comment: Any errors in indentation is because of the mechanics of copy-paste

Comment: I deleted your comment before because it's not acceptable to have people email you for the code. Include a link here or make your question verbose enough! Also, if you break stuff by copy&paste you need to FIX this!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and/or http://sscce.org on how to provide a *minimal working example*; we don't need or want the whole code, but something that can be run and shows the problem is useful. In general, why use a global variable at all? Your functions don't seem to be returning things, why not have them return whether or not to keep going?

Comment: I reread the code above and the indentation is correct. The reason I didn't put a link to the code at first is because anyone can go in and change it. I have put the code on a seperate page at http://labs.codecademy.com/CV9z#:workspace and I ask that no one modifies the code there so that people can see the true code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the bug. I removed the `endTurn` variable and instead made the function that ends the turn just do the turn of the next player. It also simplified my code a bit.

I am wondering though, is using this method of running a function inside of itself over and over and over again (without leaving) rather messy or maybe slowing down my program?

EDIT: I now realize that this answer does not exactly help with anyone else who is stuck with global variables...

Answer (score -3):

The previous answer I posted was just wrong, as it was based on a misinterpretation of the namespace docs as I had read them (Thanks to TheifMaster for pointing out my error), so this is a SEVERELY EDITED ANSWER:

The problem is in the while loop that I was able to read when the link to the entire code was posted after the erroneous answer I gave earlier.

```
while gameWinner==0:
    endTurn=1
    turn(player1)
    if not gameWinner==0:
        endTurn=1
        turn(player2)
```

The game can never get to player two in this loop until gameWinner!=0.
I added the entire code to my sandbox and changed it to:

```
while gameWinner==0:
    endTurn=1
    turn(player1)
    if gameWinner==0: #if player1 did not win yet
        endTurn=1
        turn(player2)
```

However, the game is still buggy... No one can win! gameWinner is not changed globally by the winGame() function until you add it to the global statement as I have shown here.

```
def winGame(player):
    global endTurn, gameWinner
    gameWinner=player
    gameWinner["score"]+=100
    debug("gameWinner == " + str(gameWinner))
    endTurn=0
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?  From what was asked, this will fix the problem.  It may not be entirely 'pythonic' to use global variables, but they exist, and the question was about why an undeclared global variable is not available in the global scope.

Comment: You only need to declare variables as global inside functions if you want to write to them (`foo = ...`). You never need to do it outside a function.

Comment: Can you provide a reference on that?  I have experienced this problem before and declaring the global variable at the beginning of the program has worked.

Comment: Okay, I have been reading up on namespaces and reviewing my notes.  You are right! (like you didn't know that!  LOL)  You only need to declare variables as globals inside functions if you want to write to them. Now the question for me becomes, "How did declaring a variable global at the beginning of the program fix it?"  Perhaps I just buried a bug...  I'm going to dig out that program and have another look at it.  Thank you!  I believe I have learned something by being wrong!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have corrected my answer to a real answer not based on a misinterpretation of the docs.  And again, Thanks for helping me correct my misunderstanding.